# How to write a Connection String for a service-based database in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: database, string, visual-studio-2015, connection

I have created a service based database in Visual Studio 2015. But I have a problem to construct a connection string, because of path to the database includes

How to write a functional connection string from this string fetched from the properties of the database?

```
 Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename="\\gbg.local\hem\utb\personal\john.doe\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\databastest_170307\databastest_170307\Database1.mdf";
Integrated Security=True
```

I've tried different ways, but none have created a usable string..

Comment: formatting, spell check

Answer (score 0):

Data Source=myServerAddress;Initial Catalog=myDataBase;User Id=myUsername;Password=myPassword;

hope this would help you...

Answer (score 0):

You could use this standard security Connection string:

```
Data Source=myServerAddress;Initial Catalog=myDataBase;User Id=myUsername;Password=myPassword;
```

You could also try to copy it from the properties of your database. Goto your view tab, select server explorer. Right click>properties, and from there copy the text from the field Connection String.

Comment: I have done that, but it's not possible to convert the Connection string to a string in C Sharp. It might have something to do with the two backslashes in the path. Like this: 
SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename="\\gbg.local\hem\utb\personal\john.doe\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\databastest_170307\databastest_170307\Database1.mdf";Integrated Security=True");
Sorry for the poor pasting.

Comment: Have you tried the 'System.Data.Common.DbConnectionStringBuilder' class? It will let you parse and rebuild existing connection strings.

Answer (score 0):

When you open Server Explorer window on vs15, you can see your database under Data Connections tab.
Right click your Database1.mdf file then choose properties. Under Connection category, you can find your connection string.
OR
If you add entity data model to your project, it detects your .mdf file and creates connection string for you in app/web.config.